# Windows forms application tracing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

We have a .net Windows Forms Application running in production. Is there any Free Tool that we can install to check which method of which class is called and what is the sequence?
Tried CLR Profiler, but it seems to show only the memory usage but not method call tree.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to do changes on this software or do you just have a software which you want to trace?

Answer (score 2):

**Ants Performance Profiler:**

You could use the following Ants Performance Profiler.

> ANTS Performance Profiler is a code profiler for .NET desktop,
>   ASP.NET, and ASP.NET MVC applications.  It helps you debug your
>   application quickly by giving you a complete picture of your
>   application's performance.

[Ants Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)

**Visual studio profiler:**

Visual studio has it's own free profiler build in as well.

[Visual studio profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337887.aspx)

Tutorial:

[Visual studio profiler tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)

**JetBrains:**

I recommend the following profiler created by *JetBrains*.

[JetBrains Profiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

JetBrains created a lot of helpful tool for Visual Studio, best example is: ReSharper.
You should definitely try this profiler.

All profilers will provide you the methods within the application, and more important: how many times they are called. You should always try to reduce these calls if possible.